# Exporting Excel Data from Webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am currently trying to write a python script that will open my companies inventory system which is a link in google chrome, sign in, and then click the save as excel button that is posted on top of a specific page. This will hopefully automate the process of opening the link, navigating over to the tab, clicking export, then exporting this data daily.

Any idea of where to start? I was thinking maybe can get this done using web scraping but not sure with the log in details needed. Also, how can I export this file once in? Just need some ideas to start me on this journey. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: At the moment the question is too broad and lacks details that will help us to provide specific help, e.g. it may be that the inventory system has an API or you may just need to replicate the requests being made or you may need a more specific tools like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply start with selenium python automation**

> Divide you whole process in smaller tasks and write python code
> for that each task:)